# The first layer's weights don't change after training when using Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, training-data

Some people discussed this issue before, but they generally converge to gradient vanishing as the root for this issue.

But in my model, there is only two hidden layers which is unlikely stuck on gradient vanishing, as shown below:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import keras
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop

batch_size = 128
num_classes = 10
epochs = 20

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

x_train = x_train.reshape(60000, 784)
x_test = x_test.reshape(10000, 784)
x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
x_train /= 255
x_test /= 255

y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='random_uniform',input_shape=(784,)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(512, kernel_initializer='random_uniform',activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, kernel_initializer='random_uniform',activation='softmax'))


print (model.get_weights().__len__())
for i in range(6):
    print (str(i), "th layer shape: ", model.get_weights()[i].shape ,model.get_weights()[i].__len__(), "mean: ", np.mean(model.get_weights()[i]), "std dev: ", np.std(model.get_weights()[i]))
    print ("Before Training")
    print (model.get_weights()[i][0])


class LossHistory(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
        self.losses = []

    def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
        self.losses.append(logs.get('loss'))

batch_history = LossHistory()

model.summary()

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=RMSprop(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(x_train, y_train,
                    batch_size=batch_size,
                    epochs=epochs,
                    verbose=1,
                    validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
                    callbacks = [batch_history])

for i in range(6):
    print (str(i), "th layer shape: ", model.get_weights()[i].shape ,model.get_weights()[i].__len__(), "mean: ", np.mean(model.get_weights()[i]), "std dev: ", np.std(model.get_weights()[i]))
    print ("After Training Training")
    print (model.get_weights()[i][0])
```

I took screenshot of the weights before/after training. In summary, the first layer's weights don't change after training, but the second layer's weights do change. (I only show one section of the first row in the weight matrix due to the large number of parameters)

First Layer:
Before Training
[image]

First Layer: After Training
[image]

Second Layer: Before Training
[image]
Second Layer: After Training
[image]

Comment: Without seeing the rest of the code, it's hard to know.

Comment: @StephaneBersier Just updated the rest of the code. Hope this makes it more clear to you

Comment: It's still missing some of the code, but now I just noticed that you use `'random_uniform'` to initialize the weights, which is typically not a good initializer. Have you tried using He normal initialization instead?

Comment: Actually, that shouldn't matter much in your case. Nevermind.

Comment: Can you post the code which outputs the weights before and after training? Also, I would like to know the value of `EPOCHS`

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal I update it to the full code. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some debugging, I realize that the weights matrix indeed changed after training, even though the first row (in the screenshot) of the (784, 512) matrix does look like never changed.

The reason is that I'm using pre-processed mnist data, which is a hand-writing digits image data set, and only those parts with ink will be encoded with certain RGB values. In another words, those marginal area is all '0's. For example, the first row of the image 2d matrix is always '0's. So inside the weight matrix of the first hidden layer, the very first entry of each of the 512 weight vectors will always be updated using (dJ/da_1)*(da_1/dw_i1), while (da_1/dw_i1) = x_1 which is '0' throughout all training samples as described above. so it never gets updated.